# Java split string with 2 delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to split up some strings using `String.split()`.

I want it to split a String based on the characters: `"++"` and `"+"`. For example, `"1 + 1"` would be split into `{1, +, 1}` and `"1 ++ 1"` would be split into `{1, ++, 1}`. I have written this line to split up the text:

```
String[] temp = tokens.split("(?<=(\\++)|(\\+))|(?=(\\++)|(\\+))");
```

This works fine for `"1 + 1"` (output: `{ 1, +, 1 }`) however it does not work for `"1 ++ 1"` (output: `{ 1, +, +, 1 }`). I know I can just convert it into an ArrayList and find a `"+"` followed by a `"+"` and simply combine them into one token however I am very curious if it possible to do this with the `split()`?

Comment: Do you always have spaces between your tokens? If yes then `split ("\\s+")` would be simpler.

Comment: Try using the greedy quantifier "*". Haven't tested this: (\\+) *

Comment: No, I'd like to keep it so that it could be 1++1 or 1 ++1 or 1+ 1, etc.

Comment: The greedy modifier doesn't seem to work...

Comment: You can't split on `+` and keep `+` as a token at the same time!

Comment: Not sure why you are doing this, but parsing a mathematical expression with regex is not a good idea. Even with the simplest case without `()`, which is parsable with regex, you need to lay out the grammar first before attempting to write any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to split on zero or more spaces which has

- digit before it and operator after it like `12|+ 32` (I marked such placed with `|`)
- or operator before and digit after it `12 ++|32`.

Your split can look like

```
split("(?<=\\d)\\s*(?=[+])|(?<=[+])\\s*(?=\\d)")
```

DEMO:

```
String[] data = {"1++1" , "1 ++1", "1+ 1"};
for (String str : data){
    for (String token : str.split("(?<=\\d)\\s*(?=[+])|(?<=[+])\\s*(?=\\d)")){
        System.out.println("token: <"+token+">");
    }
    System.out.println("--------");
}
```

Output (I surrounded tokens with `<` and `>` to show you that they also get rid of spaces):

```
token: <1>
token: <++>
token: <1>
--------
token: <1>
token: <++>
token: <1>
--------
token: <1>
token: <+>
token: <1>
--------
```

Comment: I am not relying on spaces, I am just removing them if there are any (notice I used `*`, which means *zero or more* not `+` which means *once or more*)

Comment: Sorry it took me a second to understand how the code worked but I see how it doesn't rely on spaces.

Answer (score 0):

A greedy quantifier works for me:

```
String [] cases = { "1+1", "1++1"  };
for (String str: cases) {
  String out [] = str.split("(\\+)*");
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(out));
}
```

generates:

```
[1, , 1]
[1, , 1]
```

If this doesn't cut it, then post more test cases.

Comment: "*For example, `"1 + 1"` would be split into `{1, +, 1}`*" your solution will not produce this result.

Comment: It splits it up but as Pshemo pointed out it doesn't keep the "+" or "++". I tried adding the lookaheads ?<=, ?< and turned the split into regex "(?<=(\\+)*)|(?=(\\+)*)" but it throws an exception.